# jQuery-UI Collapsible Tabs can't collapse independently

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'd like to be able to create two or more collapsible tab widgets. However, when I try even a very simple case, collapsing a tab in the first widget will "wiggle" the second widget around undesirably. Am I doing something wrong in this example to cause this? Is this a bug? Does anyone know how I can make these tabs collapse independently?

To produce the issue I'm talking about, collapse one of the tabs in the first widget. When you do so, you will see the second widget move a distance equal to the height that was collapsed in the first widget.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KP2s8/3/

HTML:

```
<h2>Collapsible Tabs Bug</h2>
<div style="height: 800px;"> 
    <div id="tabs_a" style="width: 300px;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs_a-1">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_a-2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_a-3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs_a-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_a-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_a-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs_b" style="width: 300px; float: right;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs_b-1">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_b-2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_b-3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs_b-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_b-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_b-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabs_a').tabs({ collapsible: true }).draggable({ snap: true });
        $('#tabs_b').tabs({ collapsible: true }).draggable({ snap: true });
})
```

Comment: I think these are independent can you please explain more what is issue

Comment: I've edited the question to be more specific about the issue.

Comment: Please check this fiddle you want like http://jsfiddle.net/KP2s8/1/ this

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma I'm not sure why, but adding a "float" css rule to both widgets seems to solve the problem. If neither of them have the float rule, the same undesirable behavior occurs. I'll accept the first answer that can explain this. Thanks for your comment! :)

Comment: So given fiddle is not working as you expected, is not then please update your fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Please see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KP2s8/4/)

```
<h2>Collapsible Tabs Bug</h2>
<div style="height: 800px;"> 
    <div id="tabs_a" style="width: 300px; float:left;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs_a-1">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_a-2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_a-3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs_a-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_a-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_a-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs_b" style="width: 300px; float: right;">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs_b-1">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_b-2">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs_b-3">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs_b-1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_b-2">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
        <div id="tabs_b-3">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```